# A Rule of Divisibility by 13 - Codewars python challenge (RecursionError)

Tags: python-3.x

**Instructions:**

When you divide the successive powers of 10 by 13 you get the following remainders of the integer divisions:

1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4.

Then the whole pattern repeats.

Hence the following method: Multiply the right most digit of the number with the left most number in the sequence shown above, the second right most digit to the second left most digit of the number in the sequence. The cycle goes on and you sum all these products. Repeat this process until the sequence of sums is stationary.

...........................................................................

Example: What is the remainder when 1234567 is divided by 13?

7×1 + 6×10 + 5×9 + 4×12 + 3×3 + 2×4 + 1×1 = 178

We repeat the process with 178:

8x1 + 7x10 + 1x9 = 87

and again with 87:

7x1 + 8x10 = 87

...........................................................................

From now on the sequence is stationary and the remainder of 1234567 by 13 is the same as the remainder of 87 by 13: 9

Call thirt the function which processes this sequence of operations on an integer n (>=0). thirt will return the stationary number.

thirt(1234567) calculates 178, then 87, then 87 and returns 87.

thirt(321) calculates 48, 48 and returns 48

**My Code:**

```
def thirt(n):
    a = []
    n = [int(i) for i in list(str(n))][::-1]
    l = [1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4][:len(n)]
    y = sum([a * b for a,b in zip(n,l)])
    a.append(y)
    for c in a:
        if a.count(c) == 1:
            thirt(c)
        else:
            return c
thirt(5634)
```

When I run this I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(thirt(8529), 79)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 9, in thirt
    thirt(i)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 9, in thirt
    thirt(i)
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 9, in thirt
    thirt(i)
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 3, in thirt
    n = [int(i) for i in list(str(n))][::-1]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object
```

when I remove some part of the code and leave it like

```
def thirt(n):
    n = [int(i) for i in list(str(n))][::-1]
    l = [1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4][:len(n)]
    y = sum([a * b for a,b in zip(n,l)])
    return y
thirt(5634)
```

I get **148** in the output, and then I **thirt(148)**, I get **57**, which is the desired answer, same goes for other examples as well.

so I just need a proper way to recur this function, and I just want it to stop as soon as the values start repeating, i.e. I want the loop of recursion to *break* as soon as I get two 57's in a row, and then I need it to return 57.

But I can't figure out a proper way to do it, because this is the first time I've applied recursion in a function, my code is really messed up, I'll really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error `depth exceeded while getting the str of an object` because you are assigning the list of digits `n` to the same variable name as the function parameter `n`. That means after the first recursive call, you are running `[int(i) for i in list(str(n))][::-1]` on a list of individual digits, and then a list of lists, and so on, rather than a single input number as you're expecting.

Once you fix that, you run into the issue of how you are checking for whether to make the recursive call:

```
a = []
a.append(y)
for c in a:
  if a.count(c) == 1:
    thirt(c)
```

I can see what you're trying to do, and it will not work in recursion because every time the function is called, `a` is reset to an empty list. That means `a.count(c) == 1` is always true, and your function will go into an infinite recursive loop.

Instead, for this algorithm all you need to do is check whether your newly calculated `y` is equal to the number `n` that was passed to the function. If they're the same, that means you've gotten the same number twice in a row, so the algorithm is done.

After that is fixed, it will look like you're getting somewhere. You can use this logic:

```
if n != y:
  thirt(y)
else:
  print(y) # expected answer outputted to console
  return y
```

Except when you call `thirt(1234567)`, the value returned is `None` ! What the heck? I printed `y` and it's correct, it's right there! What is happening is, the inner-most call to `thirt` is returning the number you need, but then the next level up in the function call stack doesn't do anything with it. So the function ends and returns `None`. To fix this, you need each level of the recursive call to pass its return value up the chain. So use `return thirt(y)` instead of just `thirt(y)`.

Finally, you need to account for the case when the number passed to the function is longer than 6 digits. Your `l` list needs to repeat in a cycle, not stop with the 6 numbers you've listed. You can get the list to be the length you need by multiplying it by the length of `n` divided by six, rounded up whenever there's a remainder.

After all that, you'll end up with something like the following:

```
def thirt(n):
    nList = [int(i) for i in list(str(n))][::-1]
    remainders = [1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4] * (
      len(nList) // 6 + min(1, len(nList) % 6)
    )
    
    y = sum([a * b for a,b in zip(nList,remainders)])
    if n != y:
      return thirt(y)
    else:
      return y

print(thirt(1234567)) #87
```

Comment: **Thank you** sooo much for the detailed explanation @jdaz

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what you mean?

```py
def thirt(n_raw):
    a = []
    n = [int(i) for i in list(str(n_raw))][::-1]
    l = [1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4]*(len(n)//6+1)
    y = sum([a * b for a,b in zip(n,l)])
    if(y==n_raw): return y
    else: return thirt(y)
```

I think you just went in a very wrong direction with the second half of your function, but I might misunderstood the premise behind...

Comment: yeah...I kinda figured that's where i messed up, but TY for the help :-)

Comment: See one more line - you did this wrong: `l = [1, 10, 9, 12, 3, 4][:len(n)]` (see how I put it)